# Github Actions: Copy folder from repo1 to repo2

Tags: git, batch-file, github, cmd, github-actions

I have two repositories: frontend (angular) and backend (Laravel)

I want every time a new commit made to the frontend repo a new build is created and copy the 'dist' folder from the build to another subfolder in another repository (backend).

My git action now works on creating a build what I am struggling with is the copy from one repo to another.

Here is what I have attempted to do:

```
    - name: build and deploy    
      run: |
          ng build
          git clone https://.:${{ secrets.API_TOKEN_GITHUB }}@github.com/[org]/[backend_repo].git
          copy dist
          git add public/client/dist
          git commit -m "Automatic deploy of dist"
          git push target [branch_name]
```

Comment: Does the `git push` fail? You might have to override git config with `API_TOKEN_GITHUB`

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have two repositories front-end angular and back java spring boot. So build angular project and copy dist folder into java back end target folder. finally, this working code does the following things.

1. Build angular teacher project.
2. Build angular student project.
3. upload Teacher and student as artifacts.
4. Build a java project and download teacher and student projects into the output folder.

name: Java CI with Maven

on:
push:
branches: [ master ]
pull_request:
branches: [ master ]

jobs:
BUILD_ANGULAR:
name: Teacher App
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
matrix:
node-version: ['14.x']

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
     repository: dmthew011/iteangular
     token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN || github.token }}
- name: Node $
  uses: actions/setup-node@v1
  with:
    node-version: '14.x'
- name: npm dependencies
  run: npm install     
- name: Build
  run: npm run build --configuration=qa --base-href=/
- run: mkdir angulardist && cp -r dist/* angulardist
- uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
     name: iteAngular
     path: angulardist
```

BUILD_ANGULAR_STUDENT:
name: Student App
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
matrix:
node-version: ['14.x']

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
     repository: dmthew011/itestudent
     token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN || github.token }}
- name: Node $
  uses: actions/setup-node@v1
  with:
    node-version: '14.x'
- name: npm dependencies
  run: npm install     
- name: Build
  run: npm run build --configuration=qa --base-href=/student/
- run: mkdir angulardist_student && cp -r dist/* angulardist_student
- uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
     name: iteAngularstudent
     path: angulardist_student
```

BUILD_JAVA:
name: Java Spring Boot App
needs: [BUILD_ANGULAR,BUILD_ANGULAR_STUDENT]
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Set up JDK 11
  uses: actions/setup-java@v2
  with:
    java-version: '11'
    distribution: 'adopt'
- name: Cache Maven packages
  uses: actions/cache@v2
  with:
    path: ~/.m2
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
    restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-m2
- name: Branch name
  run: echo running on branch ${GITHUB_REF##*/}
- name: current directory name
  run: echo running on branch ${PWD}
- run: mkdir staging
- run: mkdir site
- run: mkdir staging_teacher
- run: mkdir staging_student

- uses: actions/download-artifact@master
  with:
   name: iteAngular
   path: staging_teacher

- uses: actions/download-artifact@master
  with:
   name: iteAngularstudent
   path: staging_student

- name: Build with Maven
  run: mvn -B package site --file pom.xml
- run: cp target/ite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar staging
```

## Generating Zip file for EBS

```
- run: cp -r target/site/* site
- run: cp -r ebs/qa/. staging
```

## Upload site info

```
- uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
     name: itesiteInfo
     path: site
- uses: papeloto/action-zip@v1
  with:
      files: staging
      dest: staging/ite_ebs.zip
```

## Clean up

```
- run: rm -rf  staging/ite-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- run: rm -rf  staging/Procfile
- run: rm -rf  staging/.ebextensions
- run: rm -rf  staging/.platform
- uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
     name: Package
     path: staging
```